# Cannot remove some folders in \Library\Updates

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to remove some folders in /Library/Updates as they are taking up too much space on my hard disk using Terminal.
Even with `sudo`, I cannot remove the folders. Here are the error messages:

```
sudo rm -rf 001-26311
Password:
rm: 001-26311/001-26311.en_GB.dist: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/EmbeddedOSFirmware.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/001-26311.en_GB.extraInfo: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/FullBundleUpdate.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/SecUpd2020-004Mojave.RecoveryHDUpdate.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/SecureBoot.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/FirmwareUpdate.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/SecUpd2020-004Mojave.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311/macOSBrain.pkg: Operation not permitted
rm: 001-26311: Operation not permitted
```

I am using MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.
How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Try using `lsattr` and `getfacl` on the files that you can't delete. Also, there may be some security context (similar to SELinux on Linux; I'm not familiar with macOS) preventing you from having the permissions even if no attributes or ACLs with this effect are in place.

Comment: Have u try? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375597/unable-to-delete-pkg-files-in-library-updates

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải It really works, many thanks